# Can I use digital ocean spaces for user uploaded files with django?

Tags: django, file-upload, digital-ocean

I would like to have a central place for images, javascript, css, etc. to enable horizontal scaling on my Django application.

Currently I am looking at DigitalCcean spaces however in their guides it seems only possible to upload files manually using:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Does anyone have experience using DigitalOcean spaces with media files? I basically want to make sure that a file uploaded on one server, is accessible by another server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

yes you can just set a default file storage on your settings.py file like this

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

it will automatically create a media folder in your digitalocean spaces folder. Anything the user uploads like a picture in a post will be stored there in a media folder, no extra configuration needed, just add that line after configuring as seen below. For some reason the some provided digitalocean tutorial don't mention this.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'your-spaces-access-key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'your-spaces-secret-access-key'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'your-storage-bucket-name'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'your-spaces-files-folder'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/static'),
]
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Comment: How is the structure of the path for `AWS_LOCATION` do you also include the DigitalSpaces folder or not